# Is it possible to have lookup table of classes in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function:

```
template <class T, class Array>
void DumpArrayDebug(Array& out, const T& source)
```

It is supposed to be used to dump data from array classes in Maya (Autodesk app) into regular vector.
Example of such array types:

```
MFloatArray;
MColorArray;
MIntArray;
```

These classes have the same interface, yet they have no base class.
Currently I use this function in a following way:

```
MFloatArray someInternalMayaFloatData;
...
std::vector<float> buffer;
DumpArrayDebug(buffer, someInternalMayaFloatData);
```

Looking at this code makes me wonder is it possible to somehow tie 2 classes inside the template through something like lookup table? 
So that result should look something like this:

```
template <class T>
void dumpArrayDbg(const T& source, ClassLookupTable<T>& out)
```

Thus far I was able to come up with the following monstrosity:

```
template <typename T>
struct ClassLookupTable
{
    T classname;
};

template <>
struct ClassLookupTable<MIntArray>
{
    std::vector<int> classname;
};

template <>
struct ClassLookupTable<MFloatArray>
{
    std::vector<float> classname;
};

template <>
struct ClassLookupTable<MColorArray>
{
    std::vector<MColor> classname;
};

template <class T>
void dumpArrayDbg(const T& source, decltype(ClassLookupTable<T>::classname)& out)
{
    int length = source.length();
    out.clear();
    out.resize(length);
    source.get(out.data());
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I really don't see the problem with the current approach you have. It's simple, don't require specialization, or any other complexity.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard template metaprogramming technique: a traits type. The only things I would change are using standard template metaprogramming idioms (`type` is the standard name for a type trait, not `classname`) and avoid having the trait specify `vector`:

```
template <typename T>
struct MayaArrayBaseElementTrait; //The primary template should never be used.

template <>
struct MayaArrayBaseElementTrait<MIntArray>
{
    using type = int;
};

template <>
struct MayaArrayBaseElementTrait<MFloatArray>
{
    using type = float;
};

template <>
struct MayaArrayBaseElementTrait<MColorArray>
{
    using type = MColor;
};

template<typename T>
using MayaArrayBaseElementTrait_t = typename MayaArrayBaseElementTrait<T>::type;


template <class T>
void dumpArrayDbg(const T& source, std::vector<MayaArrayBaseElementTrait_t<T>>& out)
{
    int length = source.length();
    out.clear();
    out.resize(length);
    source.get(out.data());
}
```

This way, the mapping is from the Maya array type to the base element type. This gives you the freedom to create mappings to other types besides `vector`. You could create a `std::array` or `std::list` or whatever you like. Also, if you ever want to change the allocator type for the `vector`, you are free to do so, unlike your original code.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a more elegant solution?

I propose the following...

Given a simple template type list container

```
template <typename ...>
struct typeList
 { };
```

and a recursive template as follows

```
template <typename, typename>
struct lookForType
 { };

template <typename T, typename V, typename ... Ts>
struct lookForType<T, typeList<T, V, Ts...>>
 { using type = V; };

template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename ... Ts>
struct lookForType<T, typeList<U, V, Ts...>>
   : lookForType<T, typeList<Ts...>>
 { };
```

with an helper `using` to simplify the extraction of `type`

```
template <typename T, typename L>
using lookForType_t = typename lookForType<T, L>::type;
```

you can create the mapping as follows

```
using myList = typeList<MIntArray,   std::vector<int>,
                        MFloatArray, std::vector<float>,
                        MColorArray, std::vector<Color>>;
```

and get the required type using `lookForType` or `lookForType_t`

```
using l1 = lookForType_t<MIntArray,   myList>;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ...>
struct typeList
 { };

template <typename, typename>
struct lookForType
 { };

template <typename T, typename V, typename ... Ts>
struct lookForType<T, typeList<T, V, Ts...>>
 { using type = V; };

template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename ... Ts>
struct lookForType<T, typeList<U, V, Ts...>>
   : lookForType<T, typeList<Ts...>>
 { };

template <typename T, typename L>
using lookForType_t = typename lookForType<T, L>::type;

struct Color       {};
struct MFloatArray {};
struct MColorArray {};
struct MIntArray   {};

int main()
 {
   using myList = typeList<MIntArray,   std::vector<int>,
                           MFloatArray, std::vector<float>,
                           MColorArray, std::vector<Color>>;

   using l1 = lookForType_t<MIntArray,   myList>;
   using l2 = lookForType_t<MFloatArray, myList>;
   using l3 = lookForType_t<MColorArray, myList>;


   static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::vector<int>,   l1>, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::vector<float>, l2>, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::vector<Color>, l3>, "!" );
 }
```